# React Material UI ThemeProvider not being applied

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm using [@material-ui/core](https://material-ui.com/) to handle theming in my React app, but for some reason some of the styles are not being applied.

Here's my [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-sinoussi-462ed?file=/src/App.tsx) will the full code (relevant snippets below).

I followed the [example](https://material-ui.com/customization/theming/) in Material UI's docs but it doesn't seem to work.

The interesting thing is that the text does align center (which I specified in my styles), but the background color stays the default `#fafafa` instead of `#424242` as specified in my theme. So I guess the styles are being applied but my theme is not being applied to the styles.

Another weird thing is that I logged out the value of `theme.palette.background.default` within the `makeStyles` callback and it was `#424242`.

Also, if I set the value of `backgroundColor` in the `useStyles` hook to a static string like `#f00`, it does apply (the background color changes to red).

useStyles hook:

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles(
  (theme: Theme) =>
    createStyles({
      root: {
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.default,
        height: "100%",
        textAlign: "center",
        width: "100%"
      }
    }),
  { name: "App" }
);
```

App component:

```js
const App = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <>
      <CssBaseline />
      <ThemeProvider theme={darkTheme}>
        <div className={classes.root}>hello</div>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </>
  );
};
```

Theme

```js
// NOTE: gray[800] = #424242
export const darkTheme = createTheme({
  palette: { background: { default: grey[800] } }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`App` (and therefore your `useStyles` call) is outside of the element hierarchy impacted by your dark theme `ThemeProvider`. If you pull your div into its own component and call `useStyles` from there, it works fine.

```
import React from "react";

import CssBaseline from "@material-ui/core/CssBaseline";
import {
  makeStyles,
  createStyles,
  Theme,
  ThemeProvider
} from "@material-ui/core/styles";

import { darkTheme } from "./DarkTheme";

const useStyles = makeStyles(
  (theme: Theme) =>
    createStyles({
      root: {
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.default,
        height: "100%",
        textAlign: "center",
        width: "100%"
      }
    }),
  { name: "App" }
);

const Hello = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return <div className={classes.root}>hello</div>;
};
const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <CssBaseline />
      <ThemeProvider theme={darkTheme}>
        <Hello />
      </ThemeProvider>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

[image: Edit useStyles and ThemeProvider]

Comment: Yep, that works! Thank you, this is great! So just to make sure I understand correctly, because I was calling `useStyles` within the `App` component but outside the `ThemeProvider`, the theme wasn't being supplied to the `useStyles` hook?

Comment: Correct. The fact that you were **using** the class name from `useStyles` within your `ThemeProvider` is irrelevant -- you were **generating** the CSS class from outside the `ThemeProvider`.

Answer (score 0):

I also got it to work by updating your makeStyles from using

```
createStyles({
      root: {
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.default,
```

to:

```
createStyles({
      root: {
      backgroundColor: darkTheme.palette.primary.main,
```

and changed **darkTheme.ts**

to follow their keywords:

```
palette: {
    primary: { main: grey[800] }
  }
```

Here is the updated codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/fancy-tdd-p35ld?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: Interesting. This only works because you are using `darkTheme` directly, rather than using the passed in `theme`. The same works if I do `darkTheme.palette.primary.main` It will only work for the dark theme, but the moment I want to supply a different theme, it will break. I appreciate the answer though! I didn't specify in my question that I needed the ability to switch themes, but I will update it to reflect that.